# Html não carrega com o include_once() do php

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

Estou tentando rodar um arquivo php dentro do html,eu consigo o arquivo sozinho mas quando eu chamo pelo include_once() no html a pagina simplesmente não carrega.

HTML

```
<div class="input-field col s4 m3">
        <select name="estado" id="id_estados" class="browser-default" >
            <option value="" selected="selected">Escolha o estado:</option>
            <?php include_once("../CRUD/Chamadas/listarEstados.php"); ?>
        </select>
    </div>
```

PHP

```
 <?php  
    include_once("../DAO/dalLocalizacao.php");

    $dalLocalizacao = new dalLocalizacao();
    $estados = $dalLocalizacao->listarEstado();

    while($estado = mysqli_fetch_array($estados))
    {
        $item = $estado['Nome'];
        $uf = $estado['Uf'];
        $item = utf8_encode($item);
        echo '<option  value="'.$uf.'">'.$item.'</option>';
    }
?>
```

PHP2

```
<?php
include_once("../Classes/classLocalizacao.php");
include_once("../Classes/classConexao.php");
public function listarEstado()
    {
     $query = "SELECT * FROM Estado";
     $estados = $this->conexao->query($query) or die(mysql_error());
     return $estados;
    }
?>
```

Estrutura de pastas

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Acesse a página e cole pra gente as ultimas linhas do log de erros do PHP. Grande chance de ser um erro de caminho (ou mesmo de sintaxe). Quase sempre o log do PHP tem a solução pra esse tipo de problema.

Comment: desculpa a pergunta o resultado do console do browser você fala ?

Comment: Log de erros. é uma das primeiras coisas que quem usa PHP deve saber, é onde são gravados os erros todos. Normalmente, quando é usado com apache, fica no mesmo arquivo. Depende de quem configurou o servidor.

Comment: Só pra ter certeza, você está acessando os arquivos por um servidor PHP, certo?

Comment: Pela estrutura apresentada na figura, o caminho na `PHP` me parece estar correto; formulário na pasta `form` com `../DAO` sai da pasta `form` e entra na pasta `DAO`. Na PHP2 não há elementos para verificar.